# How can I enable GeoIP support in Phusion Passenger Enterprise's compilation?

Tags: nginx, passenger, geoip, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install Phusion Passenger Enterprise into an Alpine 3.8 container image by following the official documentation for standalone installs with RubyGems as follows:

- [Installing Passenger Enterprise Standalone
  from RubyGems (without RVM)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/standalone/install/enterprise/rubygems_norvm/)
- [Non-interactive, automatic, headless installs or upgrades](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/standalone/noninteractive_install.html#source-tarball-or-rubygems-installation)

However, Passenger won't start because my Nginx configuration template contains `geoip_*` instructions which the embedded Nginx core of Passenger standalone doesn't support:

```
*** ERROR: the Nginx configuration that Phusion Passenger Standalone generated internally contains problems. The error message returned by the Nginx engine is:

    nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "geoip_country" in nginx.conf:57
    nginx: configuration file nginx.conf test failed

This probably means that you have a problem in your Nginx configuration template. Please fix your template.
```

Since Passenger is compiling everything from scratch anyways, how do I ensure that GeoIP is enabled for the internal Nginx core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make this work is to use Passenger for Nginx, combined with your own Nginx install. That way you can control what modules you want to enable.